# Issue in defining parent path

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, url, angular-ui

I am developing an application in website using .net framework 4.5 and angularjs. I am facing an issue regarding parent path after publishing my project.
My project structure is-

```
 D:\abc\
     ->app
         -appdata
         -css
         -faltify
         -img
         -js
            -controllers
               LoginController.js
            -services
               LoginService.js
     ->Login.html
```

where app folder and Login.html are on same level. I am giving the path of `LoginController` and `LoginService` in `Login.html` as

```
<script src="../app/js/services/LoginService.js"></script>
<script src="../app/js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>
```

and same for other directorie's files.
I publish it on IIS server and made Login.html as default page so that when I browse it , it can display Login.html page. When I run the application locally,it runs fine. But after publishing on IIS when I brows using url using `http://localhost:8090/1` (here 1 is id of a record), it gives an error as

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
Requested URL   http://localhost:8090/1
Physical Path   C:\websites\abc\ui\1
```

When I give url as `http://localhost:8090/#/1` it works fine.But I dont want to give `#` in url. Am i giving wrong path in Login.html? Is there any solution for this? I just want to access Login.html using `http://localhost:8090/1` . Please help.

Comment: I am publishing it on `C:\websites\abc\ui`

Comment: Am I giving wrong path in `<script src="../app/js/services/LoginService.js"></script>` ?
I tried it by giving
 `<script src="js/services/LoginService.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers/LoginController.js"></script>`
too..But it can not works.

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for is html5Mode on $locationProvider.It can help you to come up with pretty urls. Have a look at https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

hope this helps

Comment: I don't want to give `#` in url..and without giving # in url,it works fine on local machine..but after publishing it on IIS it gives an error